# Alternância de logotipo automaticamente com Fade

Tags: html

Gostaria de adicionar em meu site HTML, um efeito de mudança de cor do logotipo com fade, seja javascript ou jquery.

Por exemplo:

Mudar de:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentre outras imagens, somando todas: 10 img's.

Com efeito Fade e automaticamente, sem que seja aparente algum tipo de slide ou código, ficando como logotipo normal. Alguém pode me ajudar?

HTML:

```html
<div class="logo">
    <a href="http://core-webhosting.com.br/index.html">
        <img src="http://core-webhosting.com.br/images/logo.png" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A resposta é simples cara: "Use apenas CSS".
CSS3 te permite fazer animações com transições do jeito que você quiser!

Deixe o jQuery só para aplicações que não se pode fazer com CSS3!

```css
.slider {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slide1,.slide2,.slide3,.slide4,.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371566801_p17tbs0rrjqdt1u4dnk94fe4b63.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 8s infinite;

} 
.slide2 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371565525_p17tbqpu0d69c21hetd77dh483.jpeg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade2 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 8s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
    background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371564896_p17tbq6n86jdo3ishhta3fv1i3.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade3 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade
{
  0%   {opacity:1}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 0}
  100% { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade2
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 1}
  66.666% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes fade3
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 1}
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide1'></div>
  <div class='slide2'></div>
  <div class='slide3'></div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/davidhc/pen/nLpJk

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWNOwp

Comment: Eu enfrentei problemas ao tentar alinhar a imagem no site, pode me ajudar? Ficou assim: 
 http://i.stack.imgur.com/2l9bO.png

Comment: Os arquivos:

CSS:
http://core-webhosting.com.br/downloads/style.css

HTML:
http://core-webhosting.com.br/downloads/index.txt

Comment: Esse CSS3 não alinhou bem o logotipo na página! Alguém pra ajudar?