# Alternância de logotipo com CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Preciso de um código CSS3 para alternar 20 logotipos automaticamente com fade, sem que o logotipo anterior apareça atrás. Mas não tenho ideia de como fazê-lo! Alguém pode me ajudar?

(Se alguém respondesse a última, talvez eu não precisasse perguntar novamente)

Comment: Você já fez essa pergunta aqui em outra conta sua: [Alternância de logotipo automaticamente com Fade](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85535/altern%c3%a2ncia-de-logotipo-automaticamente-com-fade)

Answer (score 5):

Existem diversas maneiras de se fazer isso, o problema é que com apenas CSS não tem como fazer dinâmico. Se você quiser adicionar mais imagens futuramente, vai ter que atualizar o seu código.
Eu faria da seguinte maneira:

Gere um sprite com as imagens que você quer alternar.
Você pode usar o Photoshop ou alguma outra ferramenta de edição de imagens ou mesmo um gerador online.

Para o exemplo eu usei este:
[http://spritegen.website-performance.org](https://spritegen.website-performance.org/)

Com o sprite em mãos basta adicionar o background-position correspondente a cada step da sua animação

[image: Flags]

```css
.flag {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/NE2SSL4.png) no-repeat -5px -5px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 11px;
    animation: flags 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes flags {
    0%   { background-position: -31px -5px  }
    10%  { background-position: -57px -5px  }
    20%  { background-position: -83px -5px  }
    30%  { background-position: -109px -5px }
    40%  { background-position: -135px -5px }
    50%  { background-position: -161px -5px }
    60%  { background-position: -187px -5px }
    70%  { background-position: -213px -5px }
    80%  { background-position: -239px -5px }
    90%  { background-position: -265px -5px }
    100% { background-position: -291px -5px }
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Você pode brincar com opacity e etc para gerar o efeito de fade..

Segue uma leitura mais profunda sobre o assunto

[https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations-1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations-1/)

Aqui uma resposta que talvez tenha algo de interessante para ti

[Como fazer animações dinâmicas com CSS3?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43144/como-fazer-anima%C3%A7%C3%B5es-din%C3%A2micas-com-css3/43223#43223)

@Edit:

Uma segunda abordagem que também pode usar é alternar a opacidade com um timing pré-determinado.

Funciona assim, você precisa fazer os cálculos e altenar a opacidade dos elementos de modo que quando um estiver sendo mostrado os outros fiquem escondidos.

Imagine o seguinte cenário, quero montar um slider com 3 imagens que dure 6 segundos.

Vamos ter isso

```
2s
```

[ 1 ] -> Mostra
[ 2 ] -> Esconde
[ 3 ] -> Esconde

```
4s
```

[ 1 ] -> Esconde
[ 2 ] -> Mostra
[ 3 ] -> Esconde

```
6s
```

[ 1 ] -> Esconde
[ 2 ] -> Esconde
[ 3 ] -> Mostra

Então sera necessário um último step para mostrar o primeiro elemento novamente, fechando 8 segundos.

E aqui o exemplo de como ficaria

```css
.flags {
    width: 16px;
    height: 11px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 1em 0;
    position: relative;
}


.flags i {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/NE2SSL4.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 11px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.flag-br {
    background-position: -31px -5px;
    animation: first_image 8s infinite;
}

.flag-se {
    background-position: -239px -5px;
    animation: second_image 8s infinite;
}

.flag-ao {
    background-position: -5px -5px;
    animation: third_image 8s infinite;
}

@keyframes first_image {
    0%     { opacity: 1 }
    33.33% { opacity: 0 }
    66.66% { opacity: 0 }
    100%   { opacity: 1 }
}

@keyframes second_image {
    0%     { opacity: 0 }
    33.33% { opacity: 1 }
    66.66% { opacity: 0 }
    100%   { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes third_image {
    0%     { opacity: 0 }
    33.33% { opacity: 0 }
    66.66% { opacity: 1 }
    100%   { opacity: 0 }
}
```

```html
<div class="flags">
 <i class="flag-br"></i>
 <i class="flag-se"></i>
 <i class="flag-ao"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Me veio a cabeça o uso de Animation disponivel no css3
Alternei apenas 10 cores, mas já da pra pegar uma base...

```css
/* Codigo CSS */
#logo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-animation: AlterarLogos 5s infinite;
    animation: AlterarLogos 5s infinite;
}
/* KEYFRAMES */ 
@-webkit-keyframes AlterarLogos {
    0% {background:red;}
    10% {background:blue;}
    20% {background:green;}
    30% {background:yellow;}
    40% {background:purple;}
    50% {background:black;}
    60% {background:white;}
    70% {background:pink;}
    80% {background:brown;}
    90% {background:grey;}
    100% {background:gold;}


}

@keyframes AlterarLogos {
    0% {background:red;}
    10% {background:blue;}
    20% {background:green;}
    30% {background:yellow;}
    40% {background:purple;}
    50% {background:black;}
    60% {background:white;}
    70% {background:pink;}
    80% {background:brown;}
    90% {background:grey;}
    100% {background:gold;}


}

EXEMPLO:
```

```html
<div id="logo"></div>
```

Comment: Eu usei esse com cores e alterei as cores por imagens, porém elas piscam ao alterar, somem em fração de segundos e alteram para outra, eu sou bastante leigo. Por favor, alguém pode fazer esse código para 10 imagens com FADE?